# Среда разработки для php

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-то среда или редактор, чтобы php-скрипты для сайта можно было отладить по котрольным точкам и т.п.?

Comment: xdebug + любая ide

Comment: Соглашусь с предыдущим комментатором. Я лично в качестве IDE использую Sublime Text 2.